# echo same string 85 times with some ascending numbers within it

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, seq

I have to create a huge file of 85 entries in the following format:

```
user_dept1=$( while read -r x && read -r y <&3; do   echo " model: $model_1  user: $x department: $y License_Used: $p_out1"; done < /home/user_files/out1.txt 3</home/dept_files/dep1.txt | ts '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

user_dept2=$( while read -r x && read -r y <&3; do   echo " model: $model_2  user: $x department: $y License_Used: $p_out2"; done < /home/user_files/out2.txt 3</home/dept_files/dep2.txt | ts '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

and so on till user_dept85

```
user_dept85=$( while read -r x && read -r y <&3; do   echo " model: $model_85  user: $x department: $y License_Used: $p_out85"; done < /home/user_files/out85.txt 3</home/dept_files/dep85.txt | ts '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Hence the strings below will be renamed every time from 1-85:

```
user_dep1 - user_dept85
$model_1 -  $model_85
$p_out1  - $p_out85
out1.txt - out85.txt
dep1.txt - dep85.txt
```

Comment: Indenting the code blocks would make this somewhat more readable...

Comment: didn't get you.

Comment: See here: [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). Thrig meant that adding 4 spaces to the beginning of a line makes it appear in fixed-width font on a grey background and that makes code much easier to read. Have a look at my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to generate 85 lines of code?

```
for a in {1..85}
do
  echo "user_dept$a=\$( while read -r x && read -r y <&3; do   echo \" model: \$model_$a  user: \$x department: \$y License_Used: \$p_out$a\"; done < /home/user_files/out$a.txt 3</home/dept_files/dep$a.txt | ts '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')"
done > resulting_code
```

The trick is to make sure that quoting is observed.  So the `$` and `"`" characters need to be quoted as `\$` and `\"`

The first 3 lines of the resulting output:

```
user_dept1=$( while read -r x && read -r y <&3; do   echo " model: $model_1  user: $x department: $y License_Used: $p_out1"; done < /home/user_files/out1.txt 3</home/dept_files/dep1.txt | ts '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
user_dept2=$( while read -r x && read -r y <&3; do   echo " model: $model_2  user: $x department: $y License_Used: $p_out2"; done < /home/user_files/out2.txt 3</home/dept_files/dep2.txt | ts '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
user_dept3=$( while read -r x && read -r y <&3; do   echo " model: $model_3  user: $x department: $y License_Used: $p_out3"; done < /home/user_files/out3.txt 3</home/dept_files/dep3.txt | ts '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: How did, i missed it anyways thanks It seems to be working, what does "\"  means here ?

Comment: If you want a `"` character to appear inside a `"..."` string then you need to quote it, eg `echo "I said, \"hello\""`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `ts` does for you, but if you can use bash arrays instead of variables numbered by name, this should do approximately what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

for n in {1..85}
do
    x=$(</home/user_files/out${n}.txt)
    y=$(</home/dept_files/dep${n}.txt)
    user_dep[$n]=$(echo " model: \$model_${n}  user: $x department: $y License_Used: \$p_out${n}" | ts '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
done

# and show results
for n in {1..85}
do
    echo user_dep${n} = ${user_dep[$n]}
done
```